# How to use a Self-Signed Certificate in Mozilla Firefox without a Server Exception?

Tags: firefox, https, ssl-certificate

I have not found a way to obtain a functioning SSL/TLS connection in Mozilla Firefox using a self-signed SSL certificate without simply adding a server exception. Other common browsers (Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome) enable you to import a self-signed certificate as a "Trusted Root Level Authority" - but this doesn't seem possible with Firefox.

Is there a way to use a self-signed SSL certificate in Mozilla Firefox without simply adding a Server Exception?

If, for example, I navigate to https://self-signed.badssl.com/ in Google Chrome, it's quite easily to prevent a "Connection not secure" warning simply by importing the certificate as a "Trusted Root Certification Authority" and restarting Chrome. This also works in Microsoft Edge.  If, however, I attempt to add the SSL certificate under "Authorities" in Firefox's "Certificate Manager" - this attempt will fail with the following error:

["This is not a certificate authority certificate, so it can’t be imported into the certificate authority list."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7uh0.png)

That error seems reasonable because the SSL cert for https://self-signed.badssl.com/ specifies a Basic Constraint of "CA:False". I know from prior experience that changing that value to "CA:True" *would* enable me to add the SSL Certificate under "Authorities" in Firefox. But Firefox will report a **MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY** after such an import, thereby preventing use of the certificate without adding a server exception.

Comment: If indeed it's not possible to use a self-signed cert in Firefox w/o simply adding a security exception - that's not necessarily a bad thing.  I've always considered such certificates a bit of a dangerous hack.  The motivation for my question is simply to understand Firefox's behavior.

Comment: Firefox is open source. If you are really interested in why Firefox checks CA certificates in a more strict way and restricts it's usage when you can try to find the source code paths and check when they were created, by whom and what commit comments were given. Or may be you could simply ask the author.